# AUCTeX with Sumatra PDF

Tags: auctex, microsoft-windows

I am syncing AUCTeX with Sumatra PDF on MSWindows. I used the instructions in  https://www.barik.net/archive/2012/07/18/154432/ (I write here the setqs instead of customization)

```
(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex) 
(setq TeX-view-program-list 
  '(("Sumatra PDF" ("\"C:/bin86/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe\" -reuse-instance" 
                      (mode-io-correlate " -forward-search %b %n ") " %o"))))
 (setq TeX-view-program-selection  
      '(((output-dvi style-pstricks) "dvips and start") (output-dvi "Yap") 
       (output-pdf "Sumatra PDF") (output-html "start")))
```

However, when there is a space in the file name (e.g. "example 1.tex"), the syncing has problems: when from Emacs I do CRTL-c CRTL-v, it opens both the the file "example 1.pdf" and a dummy "123" file, where 123 is the line number in the source file.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: The tutorial you link to is quite old. You can find the current instructions for your version of AucTeX from Emacs: `C-h i` to open the info system, `m Auctex <return>` to pick the AucTeX manual, `m viewing <return>` to open the chapter on viewers. It looks like your value for `TeX-source-correlate-method` is not in the right format. It should be `(setq TeX-source-correlate-method '((dvi . source-specials) (pdf . synctex)))`

Comment: Code that manipulates file and directory names should use the Elisp functions provided for that. It should not use just string-manipulation functions. IOW, tell Emacs that these are file names by using filename-manipulation functions.

Comment: @Tyler - `TeX-source-correlate-method` can be set to the symbol `synctex`.  Check the docstring with `C-h v TeX-source-correlate-method RET`.

Comment: The tutorial I used is the one recommend by the AUCTeX documentation https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recent AUCTeX, you can reduce the required customization if you have `SumatraPDF` in your `PATH` env. variable.  You can check if Emacs finds the executable with <kbd>ESC-: (executable-find "sumatrapdf") RET</kbd>.  If the executable is found, you only need to customize `TeX-view-program-selection` and add the following line:

```
(output-pdf "SumatraPDF")
```

Note the missing blank.

If you have to hardcode the path, you have to quote the `%b` expander with `\"`:

```el
(setq TeX-view-program-list 
      '(("Sumatra PDF"
         ("\"C:/bin86/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe\" -reuse-instance" 
          (mode-io-correlate " -forward-search \"%b\" %n ") " %o"))))
```

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion of adding the \" worked perfectly.

Comment: On the other hand, the line (output-pdf "SumatraPDF") should be added to the variable TeX-view-program-selection. Moreover, in the builtin variable TeX-view-program-list-builtin there is the same bug I had in my customization: if I view a file with a space inside its name, it also opens a dummy page with the pagenumber.

Comment: @AntongiulioFornasiero - Thanks for catching the typo, I meant `TeX-view-program-selection`, answer edited.  Reg. `TeX-view-program-list-builtin`, you're right, this issue was fixed in AUCTeX sources in April 2018, but the last ELPA release was in March 2018.  It is time for a new ELPA release `:-)`